# Find an example for norm of matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

We have known that $||A||_2\leq\sqrt{m}||A||_\infty$ for any matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{mxn}$.
I try to find an example for this "equality". Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just take the trivial example of a matrix consisting solely of the number $1$?

Comment: @IsaacSolomon It seems to me that $\|\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\|_2=2=\|\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\|_\infty.$

Comment: Not numbers, Janko. Number! The matrix $(1)$.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon, it is a good idea. I will pick this one first.

Comment: @JankoBracic  it may not be the example because it has to add $\sqrt{2}$ on the right.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon Yes, you are right! :)

Comment: @user215144 Yes, I know, I wanted to say that a matrix with all entries equal to $1$ is not an example.

Comment: For the $2\times 2$ case one can look for positive $a$ and $b$ such that $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a&b\\b& 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ will satisfy the condition. Here $\| A\|_\infty=a+b$ and now $a, b$ has to be determined in such a way that the non-zero eigenvalue of $A$ is $\sqrt{2}(a+b)$. I guess that this can be done.

Comment: In order to avoid trivial answers (such as zero or $1\times 1$ matrices), you should ask: "Given $m$ and $n$, what is a nonzero matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ such that $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{m}\|A\|_\infty$."

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\ 1&0&\cdots&0\\}.
$$